# Correct values based on reference data in Python

Tags: python, loops, join

There's a sensor dataset, and the values in value column needs to be corrected based on one specific sensor R in the data. The values are directions in degrees (circle 360 degrees). The correction method is as below formula, for each individual sensor i, calculate sum of sine /cosine differences respecting to the reference sensor and get the corrected degrees by calculating artanh. Then minus it from its original values. Vi(t) is the value of sensor i at time t, and VR(t) is the value of Reference sensor R at time t. 
[image: a busy cat]

```
date  sensor  value tag
0  2000-01-01       1    200   a
1  2000-01-02       1    200   a
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
7  2000-01-08       1    300   b
8  2000-01-02       2    202   c
9  2000-01-03       2    204   c
10 2000-01-04       2    206   c
```

I have tried some but little confused in how to complete this request in a for loop.

> 1. The timestamps for sensors are not matching. The individual sensor may have more or less timestamps than the reference sensor.
> 2. I want to add an additional column to store corrected values.

Below is the sample dataset I made. If choose sensor 2 as the reference sensor to correct other sensor values, how can I complete it in a python loop. Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
sensor1 = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8),"sensor":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],"value":[200,200,200,200,200,300,300,300],"tag":pd.Series(['a','b']).repeat(4)})
sensor2 = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range('1/2/2000', periods=10),"sensor":[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],"value":[202,204,206,208,220,250,300,320,280,260],"tag":pd.Series(['c','d']).repeat(5)})
sensor3 = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range('1/3/2000', periods=10),"sensor":[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],"value":[265,222,232,220,260,300,250,200,190,223],"tag":pd.Series(['e','f']).repeat(5)})
sensor4 = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=11),"sensor":[4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4],"value":[206,203,210,253,237,282,320,232,255,225,262],"tag":pd.Series(['c']).repeat(11)})
sensordata = sensor1.append([sensor2,sensor3,sensor4]).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an inelegant solution, using for loops and multiple merges. As an example, I use sensor4 to correct the remaining sensors. The correction formula was not 100% clear to me, so I interpreted it as adding the sine and the cosine.

```
def data_correction(vi, vr):
    return vi - np.arctan(np.sum(np.sin(vi-vr) + np.cos(vi-vr), axis=0)) # i assume sin and cosine are summed?

sensors = [sensor1, sensor2, sensor3] # assuming you want to correct with sensor 4
sensorR = sensor4.copy()    

for i in range(len(sensors)):
    # create temp dataframe, with merge on date, so that measurements line up
    temp = pd.merge(sensors[i], sensorR, how='inner', left_on='date', right_on='date')

    # do correction and assign to new column
    temp['value_corrected'] = data_correction(temp['value_x'], temp['value_y'])

    # add this column to the original sensor data
    sensors[i] = sensors[i].merge(temp[['date', 'value_corrected']], how='inner', left_on='date', right_on='date')
```

Comment: Thank you. I have figured out by my self. Will post the solution shortly.